# azure devops and VS 2017. mapping issues

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2017, repository

I have two VS solutions (test and production), mapped to respective Devops repositories.
Everything was working well, until a network crash occurred. after intranet connection was restored, I realized that Devops test repository does not recognize pending changes to my VS test solution. Instead, mapping from VS production solution to Devops production repository seems to work correctly.
I tried to cancel and re-create mappings, but Im still facing that issue. how can I fix it?
thanks

Comment: Do you mean you can not check in the pending changes of the test solution? What error did you get?

Comment: exactly. no error messages. simply, "pending changes" section can not detect changed items in my solution

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following items:

1. Go to web portal, to see whether you can access the test repository as normal.
2. If you can access the test repository, check whether you use the same account to access the repository in VS.
3. Close all Visual Studio instances, delete %LOCALAPPDATA%.IdentityService.
4. Clear Azure Devops Service caches %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache.
   Re-launch the VS and try to connect to service again.
5. Check how many workspace you have and whether you selected the correct workspace.

Comment: I deleted .IdentityService folder and all folders under Microsoft team\foundation\7.0\cache. but now I can not connect to repository. I got this error message

TF30063: not authorized to access domain.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection

Comment: Are you able to access the test repository from web portal with the credential you used in VS? It seems you don't have appropriate permission to access the repo. Please try to remove the devops service in VS and add again to see how is the result. In addition, check credential manager in Control Panel to see whether there stored related credentials to DevOps.

Comment: I think I do. I access it from VS, Team Explorer, Azure DevOps section, by clicking on repository link (something like https:// mycompany.visualstudio.com/myRepos). When I change my domain password, access to repository asks for new credentials. 
how can I remove and add devops service from my VS?

Comment: Click Manage Connections -- connect to a project, right click the service and click Remove. Usually, when you delete %LOCALAPPDATA%.IdentityService, you would need to reenter your credentials.

Comment: I did it. Right click options are all disabled

Comment: After you delete %LOCALAPPDATA%.IdentityService, did you reenter credentials for the service? If you try on other client machine, are you able to access the repo?

Comment: I deleted %LOCALAPPDATA%.IdentityService and reconnect to repos server. I can see only test repository, and remove option is still disabled

Comment: If you try on other client machine, are you able to access the repo? Could you double confirm whether you can access the repo from web portal with the credential you use in VS?

Comment: I log on repos web portal from another machine, entering my domain credentials. It seems Im just having problems to manage repository from my machine; maybe some configuration file was corrupted. If I delete %LOCALAPPDATA%.IdentityService, I can not recreate link to repository. Furthermore, I noticed that some files in my solution are not stored in Webops repository. can I add them manually?

Comment: Please check credential manager in Control Panel to see whether there stored related credentials to DevOps on your machine. Since you can access the repo from other client machine, the issue seems a cache related.